# How to display directory browser tree like control using coldfusion tags only?

Tags: coldfusion, tree, directory-structure

Few months back when I was trying some features of Coldfusion then i found that we can have directory browser control on webpage using very simple tag. But I don't remember that tag now. I remember it was an applet. I have found cftree tag but it needs bind operation and few lines of coding to display directory structure. I am not able to google it. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer to my own question at below link:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=691047

Thanks if anyone tried finding solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think its cfdirectory tag or cftree you have been looking for.